# Match functions and function calls in C using regex

Tags: c, regex, syntax-highlighting

I am fairly new into regexes, so I wrote the following simple regex using positive lookahead that detects functions and function calls in a C source file-

```
\w+(?=\s*\()
```

It works fine, but the problem is it detects non-function syntaxes like `if()`, `while()`etc  too.
I can easily avoid this by saying-

```
(if(?!\()) | (while(?!\())
```

But the problem is how to combine the second regex with the first one? I cant `OR` them, cos the first one still matches `if()`, `while()` etc and in an `OR` expression, its enough if one of the term matches.

How to combine these regexes or have a better simpler one which will not match non-function syntaxes like `if()`, `while()`

**PS**: I use the following tools to test my regexes

[GSkinner](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/)

[RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/)

Comment: What is the language/tool that you are using to process C file? If it supports look around, then you can use negative look ahead `(?!(if|while))`, followed by the regex to match the function.

Comment: I'm not convinced a regex is the right tool for this job - it's fairly easy to make things that look confusing that are hard to match correctly.

Comment: @nhahtdh I [tried](http://regexr.com?31hq1) your suggestion.It doesn't seem to work the way I intend it to. Can you just check if I've gone wrong somehere?

Comment: @Flexo Its just for me learning more of regexes :)

Comment: @PavanManjunath: [Add word-boundary](http://regexr.com?31hq7).

Comment: @nhahtdh Thanks, it works! But your new solution is missing out a corner case where the function name starts with the keywords `if`, `for`. So function names like `ifIamWrong()`, `forYouDear()` aren't matching.

Comment: @nhahtdh: http://regexr.com?31hqd

Comment: @PavanManjunath: Throw in word boundary for negative look-ahead: http://regexr.com?31hqg

Comment: @nhahtdh Ahh. Your smart! :) Thanks, you can convert your comments to an answer. One more clarification. By avoiding the `|`, we ended up ANDing the expressions. Am I right?

Comment: @PavanManjunath: Not really AND, but it's more like "followed by".

Comment: it also works without the last `\b` (`+` is greedy). and you should post it as an answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are quite a lot of assumptions when you are searching for function call in C with regex. That aside, if you are happy with what is matched (there are valid function calls that will not be matched), and you want to exclude `if` and `while` from the result list, you can use the following regex:

```
(?!\b(if|while|for)\b)\b\w+(?=\s*\()
```

The regex uses word boundary `\b` to make sure that the whole name is matched (prevent partial matching of `hile` in `while`), and the whole name is not keyword (prevent rejection of `whilenothinghappens`).